# xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'nsmap'

Tags: python, xml, zip, elementtree

I have a large number of `.zip` files in a folder. They are DAISY files. I need to:

- open each ZIP archive,
- open up the only XML file in the archive,
- extract only the numbers from the same element, for example `<meta name="dc:Identifier" content="12345-eng-epb"/>`,
- and then re-archive and rename the ZIP archive as that extracted number. For example, example `12345.zip`

This is my code:

```py
import os
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Enter the path to the folder containing the zip files
folder_path = r'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXXXXXXX\XXXXXX_Work\bookshare_DAISY\rename_test_XXXXX'

# Loop through each file in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file_name.endswith('.zip'):
        # Get the full path to the zip file
        zip_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

        # Extract the UID from the XML file in the zip file
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_file:
            for inner_file_name in zip_file.namelist():
                if inner_file_name.endswith('.xml'):
                    with zip_file.open(inner_file_name) as inner_file:
                        tree = ET.parse(inner_file)
                        root = tree.getroot()
                        uid = root.find('.//dc:identifier', root.nsmap).text

        # Remove any non-digit characters from the UID
        uid_numbers = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, uid))

        # Generate the new zip file name and path
        new_zip_file_name = f'{uid_numbers}.zip'
        new_zip_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_zip_file_name)

        # Rename the zip file
        os.rename(zip_file_path, new_zip_file_path)

print('Done!')
```

I keep running into this `AttributeError` issue `'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'nsmap'`, and I'm just not entirely sure what it means, or if I'm even really on the right track for this code to run properly.

Comment: What are you expecting the `nsmap` attribute to be?  Did you copy this code from an example somewhere?

Comment: There's only one place in the posted code where you reference `nsmap`, which is `uid = root.find('.//dc:identifier', root.nsmap).text`  The error message is telling you that `root` has type `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`, and that it has no attribute named `nsmap`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: `nsmap` does not exist in ElementTree. [tag:lxml] however provides this property on elements: https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree._Element.nsmap

Answer (score 1):

The native Python implementation of `ElementTree` does not have such an attribute. You might consider switching to the [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) version, which is the module that wherever you got the `.nsmap` reference in your code was probably using.

To aid with this task of switching over, `lxml` even provides a handy page on the [compatibility of `lxml.etree` with other `ElementTree` implementations](https://lxml.de/compatibility.html). After making sure `lxml` is installed, it should be as simple as changing your `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` line to `import lxml.etree as ET`, and the API should be backward-compatible.

From the compatibility page I linked above, we can see that in addition to supporting the `.nsmap` attribute,

> lxml.etree offers a lot more functionality, such as XPath, XSLT, Relax NG, and XML Schema support, which (c)ElementTree does not offer.

and is therefore generally preferable to the built-in `xml.etree` for anything remotely sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

I would rename and copy after parsing with the build in `xml.etree.ElementTree` to a new folder. The different namespaces can be searched with `root.find(".//{*}identifier").text`:

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# List the ZIP filess
zip_files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r".\archive"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".zip"):
            zip_files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
print(zip_files_list)

# Read the XML File into ZIP
xml_file_list = []
for zip_file in zip_files_list:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, mode="r") as f:
        for files_list in f.namelist():
            xml_file_list.append(files_list)
# Parse and copy renamed ZIP to the new directory
            with f.open(files_list, mode='r') as thefile:
                tree = ET.parse(thefile)
                root = tree.getroot()
                file_id = root.find(".//{*}identifier").text
                print(root.find(".//{*}identifier").text)
                src= zip_file
                dst= f"./archive/changed/{file_id}.zip"
                shutil.copy(src,dst)
```